# Extract function in terra package R gives memory usages spike?

Tags: r, raster, spatial, terra

I am trying to run terra::extract to sum population (from a .tif) to global regions (from a .shp). Below is a reproducible example of the code that I run. In the case below, the memory use before (A) and after (B) the extract function and after memory clearup (C) is almost similar. However, running the exact same code but with a larger .tif and .shp leads to a very large spike of memory use, where memory use is (A: 142Mb, B: 14882Mb, C: 143.3MB ). I can imagine a difference because the datasets are larger and there is more computational effort, but this seems rather excessive. Is this normal, and if not, is there a way cleaning memory on the fly during terra::extract? I am also trying to run it on a stack of rasters, but after hours of running it unsurprisingly gives an out of memory error.

```
library(terra)
myfun <- function(x){as.integer(sum(x,na.rm=T))}
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
rf <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
x <- rast(rf)
paste0("A: ",memory.size()," MB.")
a <-terra::extract(x, v, myfun, bind=TRUE)
paste0("B: ",memory.size()," MB.")
gc()
paste0("C: ",memory.size()," MB.")
```

Comment: If you want to check how much memory R is currently using, you should rather use `mem_used()` from the **lobstr** package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that first all raw data are extracted, and then the summary function is applied. If you have polygons that cover very many cells that may not be a viable approach and I will change that. For now, you may consider using `zonal` instead:

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
x <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
#a <- terra::extract(x, v, myfun)

v$ID <- 1:nrow(v)
z <- rasterize(v, x, "ID")
b <- zonal(x, z, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: can you please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74613690/how-to-assign-correct-projection-and-extent-to-a-raster-using-terra-r-package)?

Comment: Thanks, this works smoothly and fast. Maybe useful to add for others, as I want to write it to a shapefile I add `pm <- merge(v,b)`

Comment: or `pm$elevation <- zonal(x, z, sum, na.rm=TRUE)[,2]`, or `pm <- cbind(pm, b[, -1, drop=FALSE])`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the high-performance **exactextractr** package for large raster stacks.

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(exactextractr)

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- read_sf(f) # or st_as_sf(vect(f))
rf <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
x <- rast(rf)

a <- exact_extract(x, v, 'sum')
a <- as.integer(a)
```